# No application encryption key has been specified in docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, containers

I want to start work with docker. I have started nginx, laravel, and mysql containers. But I have a problem. When I want to visit my page I get:

`No application encryption key has been specified`

In my env file in cointainer I have `APP_KEY=base64:isqaS8uLDmiO47hZLTTKmheHM13uBkeA6wTWG1nF5E4=` generated by command `php artisan key:generate` from whitch i get `Application key set successfully.`.

When I check by `php artisan tinker` value `env('APP_KEY')` i get only `""`. What's more, I found that when in `.env` file is no `APP_KEY` section, this command doesn't work.

Permissions to env file looks like this:
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data    829 Sep 17 12:22 .env`

Error from log file

`[2020-09-17 12:23:19] local.ERROR: No application encryption key has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): No application encryption key has been specified. at /var /www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php:44) [stacktrace] #0 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php(422): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}('') #1 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(48): tap('', Object(Closure)) #2 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/EncryptionServiceProvider.php(24): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->key(Array) #3 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(800): Illuminate\\Encryption\\EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Encryption\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Foundat ion\\Application), Array) #4 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(682): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build(Object(Closure)) #5 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(630): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('encrypter', Array) #6 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(768): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('encrypter', Array) #7 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(946): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('encrypter') #8 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(874): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter)) #9 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(835): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies(Array) #10 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(682): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...') #11 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(630): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array) #12 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(768): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...', Array) #13 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(215): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('App\\\\Http\\\\Middle...') #14 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(189): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illumin ate\\Http\\Response)) #15 /var/www/public/index.php(60): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Response)) #16 {main} "}`

I tried to restart the server, clear the cache and remove and add a new key, but this didn't help.

EDIT:
This is my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4.0-fpm

COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

COPY database /var/www/database

WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install git && apt-get -y install zip

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY . /var/www 

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data \
        /var/www/storage \
        /var/www/bootstrap/cache

RUN  apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
        libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
        && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3 \
        && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
        && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

RUN mv .env.prod .env

RUN composer install

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

RUN chown -R $USER:www-data storage \
        && chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache\
        && chmod -R 775 storage \
        && chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache

RUN php artisan key:generate
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.6'

services: 

    app:
        container_name: laravel_app
        build: 
            context: ./
            dockerfile: development/app.dockerfile
        volumes: 
            - ./storage:/var/www/storage
        env_file: '.env.prod'
        environment: 
            - "DB_HOST=database"
            - "REDIS_HOST=cache"

    web:
        container_name: nginx_server
        build: 
            context: ./
            dockerfile: development/web.dockerfile
        volumes: 
            - ./storage/logs/:/var/log/nginx_server
        ports: 
            - 8990:80
        
    database:
        container_name: mysql_database
        image: mysql:8.0
        volumes: 
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        environment: 
            - "MYSQL_DATABSE=Baly"
            - "MYSQL_USER=admin"
            - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=admin"
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root"
        ports: 
            - 8991:3006
    
    cache:
        image: redis:3.0-alpine

volumes: 
    dbdata:
```

Comment: Please add your dockerfile

Comment: Oh sorry i forgot about this. Add in edit section.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably comes from the .env.prod usage.

In this case, .env.prod will be loaded by Docker in the OS container env variables.

And Dotnet primarily uses the environment variables of the OS.

Just to make sure, please try to set the APP_KEY value in .env.prod and restart docker : `docker-compose restart`

Answer (score 0):

The package `phpdotenv` looks at your environment variables and in some versions it decides that those variables are to be used instead of the ones in your .env file.

List your environment variables to see if `APP_KEY` is set:

```
printenv
```

Unset `APP_KEY`:

```
unset APP_KEY
```

[The source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/24510#issuecomment-395865724).

If the problem persists, try restarting `php-fpm`.

```
service php7.4-fpm restart
```